# What are the requirements to become a planet?

Tags: planet, orbit, pluto

A planet is taught to us (at primary school) as **a ball of rock that orbits around the Sun** and is **similar to our own planet, Earth** (in as a ball of rock). But of course, humans have to be more specific than that so there must be some internationally agreed on requirements to define a planet by an official committee, right? I know of an example of this is when in 2006, **these requirements were enforced and Pluto got demoted from planet status to dwarf planet status.**

Comment: Also see: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/539/how-many-planets-are-there-in-this-solar-system